# How to make like function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Code**

Detail.js

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    liked = false
  };
}

export default class Detail extends React.Component {
 render() {
  const { liked } = this.state;
  return (
   ...
   <TouchableOpacity
     onPress{() => 
       this.setState({ 
         liked: !liked,
       });
     } 
   >
    ...
   </TouchableOpacity>
   ...
  )
}
```

---

In this code, `this.state.liked` is false at first and onPress changes its state.

When coming back to this page, `this.state.linked` returns to false.

What I want to do is I wanna keep `state` in this class the latest.

So, I want to keep `this.state.liked : true` when I come back to this page until I change its' state.

Comment: Your logic is fine but keep "the state" if you will use this component in for N data for example you should pass the initial state for example {'name': 'x', liked: 'false'} and save the items in your react context or redux for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be stored it the app, when you navigate back and forth, then you need to use a common storage.

Basically when you navigate away from the page, this component `unmounts`, which means it's erased from the DOM along with it's `state`. (calling `componentWillUnmount` before it disappears)

As pointed out in the comment: solution could be something like Redux/MobX redux toolkit, etc.

You can even implement your own storage if you like, but this could get tricky if your project grow.

also a note on your constructor, change:

```
this.state = {
    liked = false // << liked: false
  };
```